# grep to exclude a symbol in the beginning

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I have an xml file and it has '<' in between the lines without escape characters in front..
So first thing i tried to parse the xml using:

```
xmllint --noout filename.xml
```

but that doesnt work.. because my xml version is 1.1 which is not supported.. 
So as an alternate I started searching for '<' excluding the beginning or the end of the sentence..

should be fairly easy..  i tried:

```
grep -v '^[<]'
```

but that is not working.. can someone help?

ex: 
filename has:

```
 <instrument F001="6-A-1046" INSTRUMENT_ID="<xyz>" >
  <field fieldname="CUR007" value="<EUR>"/>
  <field fieldname="C207" value="2023-01-11"/>
  <field fieldname="INS160" value="0"/>
  <field fieldname="PRD013" value="1020"/>
  <field fieldname="PRD150" value="0"/>
  <field fieldname="PRD205" value="0"/>
 </instrument>
```

I want output to be

```
 <instrument F001="6-A-1046" INSTRUMENT_ID="<xyz>" >
  <field fieldname="CUR007" value="<EUR>"/>
```

Comment: edited.. :) thanks

Comment: I am not able to understand the logic you need here... can you try to explain again why only first two lines are to be shown in output?

Comment: @sundeep because there's a `"<"` that is not first or last (excluding whitespace)

Comment: @thealchemist if a line contains `foo bar < xyz` should it be part of output?

Comment: @Sundeep: if the '<' is not at the beginning then definitely yes.. the idea is to check the file if it follows standard xml pattern.. am still struggling with the closíng '>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for a `<` or `>` other than the first/last non-whitespace char which should be angle brackets.

```
grep '^\s*<.*[<>].*>\s*'
```

Note that this matches the whole line, so it may be used if you are wanting to do something with the line (rather than just part of it).

---

A test:

```
grep '^\s*<.*[<>].*>\s*' << EOF
>  <instrument F001="6-A-1046" INSTRUMENT_ID="<xyz>" >
>   <field fieldname="CUR007" value="<EUR>"/>
>   <field fieldname="C207" value="2023-01-11"/>
>   <field fieldname="INS160" value="0"/>
>   <field fieldname="PRD013" value="1020"/>
>   <field fieldname="PRD150" value="0"/>
>   <field fieldname="PRD205" value="0"/>
>  </instrument>
> EOF
```

Output:

```
<instrument F001="6-A-1046" INSTRUMENT_ID="<xyz>" >
 <field fieldname="CUR007" value="<EUR>"/>
```

Comment: `\s` wont be recognized by all grep implementations... can use `grep '^[[:space:]]*<.*<'` or `grep '^[[:blank:]]*<.*<'`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bohemian .. and about searching a '>' other than at the end..?

Comment: @thealchemist I have edited the answer to match either angle brackets other than where they should be.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a different sample to add some more cases

```
$ cat ip.txt
foo bar < xyz
<123 abc <42> >
  <good>
bad > line

$ # get lines having < not at start of line
$ grep '[^[:blank:]].*<' ip.txt
foo bar < xyz
<123 abc <42> >

$ # get lines having > not at end of line
$ grep '>.*[^[:blank:]]' ip.txt
<123 abc <42> >
bad > line

$ # combining the two
$ grep -E '[^[:blank:]].*<|>.*[^[:blank:]]' ip.txt
foo bar < xyz
<123 abc <42> >
bad > line
```

- `[:blank:]` represents space and tab characters
- so `[^[:blank:]]` will match a non-blank character